# How to redirect after redirect?

Tags: php

after redirect to google I want to go back to my homepage automatically. I'm trying to use API on this code.

```
public function update_order(){
        $nom = $this->uri->segment(3);

        $data_order = $this->data->getdataorder2($nom);
        foreach($data_order as $order){
            $nama = $order->nama;
            $email = $order->email;
            $telepon = $order->telepon;
            $tanggal = $order->tanggal;
            $waktu = $order->waktu;
            $jumlahorang = $order->jumlah_orang;
            $catatan = $order->catatan;
        }



        $data=  array(
            'status' => 'confirmed' 
            );

        $this->data->simpanupdateorder($nom,$data);

        **redirect('http://google.com)->redirect('index.php/welcome/index');**


    }
```

Comment: This is not possible since you can not control the google page itself. Can you explain what you want to achieve so we might find a workaround?

Comment: Trying to multiple redirect, google.com its only for example. I want to using it to my api so when the data already send to api site it's also update my data in database. it's hard to explain :/

Comment: Thank you it's already running, but I still looking for the code to give a time to redirect site. when i open google through my redirect code, it's only for several time and then go back to my homepage. it's posible ?

Comment: Well it‘s impossible to every external website because of the reason above.   My guess: you want to display the status confirmed on your Index/welcome page but it is displaying the data before the query is executed right?

Comment: yeah like that, any other way bro?

Comment: try this:     redirect('index.php/welcome/index'); exit();

Comment: No, it is NOT possible to go to google and get back to the page a few seconds later. You are losing the control over the script after the redirect because the script should end over there. BUT the database is waaaaay faster than php itself. And since PHP is sync, the database entry will ALWAYS be updated BEFORE you redirect. You can redirect to your index without any problems. The data will always be saved before.

Comment: doesn't work but thank you for helping I think I should find the other way

Comment: i just trying to add setTimeout script to site that I open through my code. I know it's heard imposibble but I just curious hehehe.

Comment: Oh just read the answer from the other guy below... He's right, "redirect()" isn't even a redirect call from PHP lol. I rly need to go to bed. He wrote everything you should know imo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Edit:

After trying I've realised that Google isn't allowing doing this (iframe) either.

```
This content can’t be shown in a frame
There is supposed to be some content here, but the publisher doesn’t allow it to be displayed in a frame. This is to help protect the security of any information you might enter into this site.
Try this "open in a new tab".
```

Thus, there's no solution for you that I'm aware of, but this solution may help for other websites.

---

> TL;DR: You can't redirect again after leaving your domain.

Once you're out of your hosting zone you have no more control over the code. You can redirect your website to Google with something like,

```
<html>
<?php
header('Location: https://www.google.com/');
exit;
?>
```

After your page is redirected to google and re-opened, there's no going back.

The best you can do is opening webpage in iframe and then going back. (Which I'm not sure why would be needed.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Your Title</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body, html
            {
                margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;
            }

            #content
            {
                position:absolute; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; top: 0px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" src="https://www.google.com" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This will open full page Google in your website zone, and you can implement your php code here.